# Sequencing HTTP Post requests

Tags: php, objective-c, http-post

I am absolutely losing my mind. I have two http post calls that are sequenced. The first returns successfully. When that happens, the second call is executed, but it never returns. I've checked everything. I have my php script boiled down to where it takes no arguments and just returns a string. But it still doesn't come back. Am I not allowed to sequence HTTP requests like this? Or am I just missing something stupid?

I've tried everything that I can think of, but I'm getting nowhwere. If I can't solve this, my app is dead in the water. Emphatic help request!!!

Here is the first call. This one works just fine:

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&id=%@&password=%@",
                  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"id"],
                  passwordTextField.text];

NSString *script = @"verifyPassword.php";

MyDownloader *d = [[MyDownloader alloc] initWithPost:post script:script];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(verificationResultsReceived:)
                                             name:@"connectionFinished"
                                           object:d];

[d.connection start];
```

This is the notification method for that call.

```
- (void) verificationResultsReceived: (NSNotification *) n
{
    MyDownloader *d = [n object];

    [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];

    if ([n userInfo]) {
        NSLog(@"information retrieval failed");
    } else {

        NSArray *response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:d.receivedData options:kNilOptions error:nil];

        if (response) {
            if ([[response valueForKey:@"result"] isEqualToString:@"success"]) {
                // password is verified - OK to update settings
                [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];

                NSString *post = @"";
                NSString *script = @"test.php";
                MyDownloader *d1 = [[MyDownloader alloc] initWithPost:post script:script];

                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                         selector:@selector(updateResultsReceived:)
                                                             name:@"connection2Finished"
                                                           object:d1];
                    NSLog(@"I got this far!");
                [d1.connection start];

            } else {
                // incorrect password entered - notify user and halt
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Incorrect Password"
                                                                message:@"Invalid password entered. Please try again."
                                                               delegate:self
                                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];

                [alert show];
            }

        } else {
            NSLog(@"The server has responded with something other than a JSON formatted object");
        }
    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name: @"connectionFinished"
                                                  object:d];
}
```

And this is the next notification monitor. It never gets here! Why????

```
- (void) updateResultsReceived: (NSNotification *) n
{
    NSLog(@"But why don't I see this?");

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name: @"connection2Finished"
                                                  object:d];
}
```

If it helps, here is the MyDownloader class:

```
- (id) initWithPost: (NSString *)post
            script : (NSString *)script
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        self->_mutableReceivedData = [NSMutableData new];

        //Encode the post string using NSASCIIStringEncoding and also the post string you need to send in NSData format.
        NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

        //You need to send the actual length of your data. Calculate the length of the post string.
        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

        //Create a Urlrequest with all the properties like HTTP method, http header field with length of the post string.
        //Create URLRequest object and initialize it.
        self.request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

        // make a string with the url
        NSString *url = [@"http://www.mySite.com/" stringByAppendingString:script];

        // Set the Url for which your going to send the data to that request.
        [self.request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

        //Now, set HTTP method (POST or GET).
        [self.request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

        //Set HTTP header field with length of the post data.
        [self.request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

        //Also set the Encoded value for HTTP header Field.
        [self.request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];

        // Set the HTTPBody of the urlrequest with postData.
        [self.request setHTTPBody:postData];

        self->_connection =
        [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:self.request delegate:self startImmediately:NO];

    }

    return self;
}

- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *) connection
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
        postNotificationName:@"connectionFinished" object:self];
}
Thanks for any advice.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you do in your `MyDownloader` class but let me guess. You create a `NSURLConnection` instance and catch its `connectionDidFinishLoading` where you send the notifications.

One thing you have to remember is that when you create the connection with `initWithRequest`, it is actually started.

> **Discussion**
>   This is equivalent to calling `initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately:` and passing `YES` for `startImmediately`.

Thus, `[d.connection start];` will presumably have no effect as the connection is already started. Maybe it has returned already before you could register as the observer!

BTW, the preferred pattern for a worker class such as your downloader is a [Singleton Pattern](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Singleton.html). Maybe you want to look at that one class always knows what connections are active.

Comment: Thanks. I've update my post to add the MyDownloader class code. You're half right. I do create an NSURLConnection, but I don't start it immediately, which is why I do that connection start.

Comment: No, my point is that `initWithRequest` does indeed start the connection. Look in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001697-BAJDDIDG).

Comment: OK. Please take a look at what I did above in my edit. I registered that observer *before* I made the first call. That way I know that if my the notification from the first call is received, but not the second, it cannot be due to a race condition. Do you agree that this proves that the problem is something else?

Comment: BTW, not to start an off-topic debate, but I disagree with the point that the connection is started. If I comment out the line `[d.connection start]` in my first http call, I get NO response at all. In case it was overlooked, my call to `initWithRequest` included a boolean value of `NO` for the `startImmediately` parameter.

Comment: Your posted code is not helping. You need to show the callback where you fire the notification. How do you know which notification to fire?

Comment: That solved it. You made me realize that wasn't looking deeply enough into the MyDownloader class. I've added another method to my post to show where I am posting the notification so `connectionFinished`. But where I set up my observer for the second connection, I changed it's name to `connection2Finished` so as not to conflict with the first connection. I wasn't thinking about where my notification was posting to. Problem solved. Thanks for sticking with me. I really appreciate it!